# cross-compile opencv with gstreamer

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I am trying to cross-compile opencv with gstreamer for armhf. I use the following command :

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=(path_to)/opencv_contrib/modules/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=(path_to)/opencv/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake  (path_to)/opencv
```

My probleme is that the cmake can't find gstreamer for armhf... It is quit normal because i have not installed it on my computer (i have installed libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev package but only for i386 architecture...).

How can i install "libgstreamer1.0-dev" and "libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev" packages for armhf architecture in order to enable the cmake to find gstreamer when cross-compiling ?

Thank you for your help !
Have a good day.

Comment: Sometthing like `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf; sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0:armhf libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0:armhf`

Comment: Thank you @Velkan. However, apt can't find the packages... I suppose i should add something into /etc/apt/sources.list ? what sould i add ? (i am in ubuntu 16.04 xenial...)

Comment: They should be in the main repositories. Maybe make sure that there are no things like 'deb [amd64,i386] ...' in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (If there are - add `armhf` to them). Also, verify that the package names are correct: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgstreamer1.0-0

Comment: I have nothing like "deb [amd64,i386]" in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, however i cannot install any armhf package...